# Iterating over a list of lists

Tags: loops, python-3.x

My *list* looks like this:

```
['"date","supermarket","categoryA",10',
'"date","candy store","categoryB",5',
'"date","drugstore","categoryC",6',
'"date","supermarket","categoryA",20',
'"date","candy store","categoryB",2',
'"date","drugstore","categoryC",90']
etc
```

I'm trying to aggregate the numbers per category -- categoryA B C etc

So far, It's been three days of mostly sideways action. I really should get a book on Python as I've just jumped in and now here I'm asking you guys.

I know how to do this in mysql but that logic is not helping me here.

My code:

```
for x in range(0 , len(list)):
    for y in list[x][2]:
        value += list[x][3]
```

Tearing my hairs out, and I don't have many of those left...

Comment: I dont' see a list of lists, just a single list, did you make a mistake?

Comment: The "list" you pasted here is a list with exactly one element in it (a string). Could you clarify what your actual input looks like?

Comment: Sorry, I think there are commas in between the ' ' there

Comment: So it is a list of strings, not list of lists?

Comment: The current list you have is a list of 6 strings. (The first string is `'"date","supermarket","categoryA",10'`.)

Comment: Alright; I see the distinction. Will try to be more careful with my words.

Comment: @MerynDH If the input you have is really what you've shown above, then the accepted answer can't possibly work.

Comment: Its a list of financial statements and therefore I did simplify it. Nevertheless, it does work. I'll recheck whether I missed something.

Comment: It does work, and the dataset really looks like represented above. The only thing I would like to add to the solution is that it aggregates per month; the current dataset has multiple months. Awesome resource SO, and thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use dictionary to hold the aggregation and iterate list using `in`:

```
aggregate = {}
for x in list:
    if (x[2] not in aggregate):
        aggregate[x[2]] = 0
    aggregate[x[2]] += x[3]
```

The above assumes your list of lists looks like this:

```
[
    ["date","supermarket","categoryA",10],
    ["date","candy store","categoryB",5]
]
```

Comment: @krzyk I don't see how your code would work on the input you've suggested. (You would presumably get an `IndexError` when you tried to use `x[2]` or `x[3]`, since each inner list has only one element.)

Comment: @smarx Yes, I copy pasted too much, I removed the `'`

Answer (score 0):

Using python dictionaries, simplifies lot of things. This would work:

```
category_aggregate_dictionary = {}
for x in range(0 , len(list)):
    for y in list[x][2]:
        value = list[x][3]
        category_aggregate_dictionary[y] = 0 if category_aggregate_dictionary.get(y, None) == None
    category_aggregate_dictionary[y] += float(value)
```

Finally, `category_aggregate_dictionary["categoryA"]` should give you aggregate number of categoryA.

Hope it Helps : )

Comment: As @smarx mentioned, this is assuming that you actually have list of lists, instead of list of comma separated strings.

Answer (score 0):

Here I've assumed you actually have a list of lists. (See my value for "entries" below.)

```
from collections import Counter

entries = [
    ["date", "supermarket", "categoryA", 10],
    ["date", "candy store", "categoryB", 5],
    ["date", "drugstore", "categoryC", 6],
    ["date", "supermarket", "categoryA", 20],
    ["date", "candy store", "categoryB", 2],
    ["date", "drugstore", "categoryC", 90]
]

# A Counter is much like a dictionary with a default value of 0
category_counts = Counter()

for entry in entries:
    category = entry[2]
    count = entry[3]
    category_counts[category] += count

# You have the counts already at this point. This loop will
# just print them out in sorted order (by category name).    
for category in sorted(category_counts.keys()):
    print('{}: {}'.format(category, category_counts[category]))

# Output:
# categoryA: 30
# categoryB: 7
# categoryC: 96
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with a list of string like that you can use a `ast.literal_eval()` function in order to evaluate your strings as tuples then use `defaultdict()` for aggregating the numbers:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> d = defaultdict(int)
>>> for item in lst:
...     *_, cat, num = literal_eval(item)
...     d[cat]+=num   
... 
>>> d
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'9': 0, 'categoryA': 30, 'categoryC': 96, 'categoryB': 7})
```